# How to set margin to the responsive template without ruining it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using downloaded bootstrap template for my Web Application.It had the side-bar menu I deleted it thought irrelevant.Now I have to add the left margin for the body of template.When adding left-margin it collapsed. How to add left margin without ruining it.

Please suggest.

Comment: could you create a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put a place holder `<div>` where the sidebar used to be. Make sure it has the same width, height, padding, margin, position, and float properties as the sidebar then set `visiblity: hidden;`. That way no collapse.

Note that `<div>` should be empty or do this: `<div>&nbsp;</div>`.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. Yes I can put a place holder for now to solve the problem. But I wanted to know whether it is possible to set margin or not that will be helpful through out the project. Anyway your answer make sense.